# how to find the position of a library by name on a remote computer

Tags: linux, compilation, flags

I am a newbie to the linux system. I am using a remote computer to do computing for my research. When it turns to compile my fortran code, I find that I do not know how to find the position of a library on the computer. For this instance I need to access to MKL and fftw, but I am using a pgi version of mpif90 compiler. In my impression this can be done by some command like "find -name ..." But I do not remember the details. Anyone can help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do the fortran libraries have their default path? Like: /opt/ibmhpc/pecurrent

Comment: I am not sure. The directories under opt are "dell lsi moab rh".

Answer (score 1):

```
find / -name <fileName>
```

will find from root path, you can change `/` to whatever directory you are trying to find from.

In your case, if you want to find if a lib is installed in your system:

```
locate <libName>
```

`whereis` could do it too.i.e:

```
whereis fftw
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. In my case I only know a rough name of the library. As I stated in my question I only know I need MKL and  fftw for pgi15.3 version of mpif90. If you were me, how would you locate the exact libraries? Can you write a sample command line? Thanks.

Comment: try using wildcard to search for the libraries:   `find / -type f -name "*name*.so"`

Comment: Or  `find / -type f -name "*name*.a"` ; or `echo ${MKLROOT}`